# I specified new version of Log4J but still dependencies also show old version

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have a project that uses SLF4J also SLF4J uses Log4J 1.2.17 (as a default without specify any version in pom.xml).

Hi, I want to upgrade Log4J version to 2.17.1, there is information about how to do it
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

and I added below code to my pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

then when I check Maven Dependecies it shows old version and new version in my project

[image: maven dependencies]

Currently I'm confused about "did I upgrade Log4J or not". How can i be sure?

Comment: It might be a transitive dependency. Try `mvn dependency:tree` to find out where it comes from.

Comment: First you should clean up your dependencies because you jul-to-slf4j, log4j-1.2 and log4j 2.x and logkit and it looks you have a messed up dependencies related to logging...without the whole project it's impossible to gues something...

Comment: I checked dependency tree and found that I use com.atlassian.bamboo:atlassian-bamboo-web:jar:6.8.1 in my project and one of its dependencies is  Log4J 1.2.17.
I'm noob for Java so I think I can't make version upgrade of dependent component of component that I added to my project, right? @marstran

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue excluding old dependencies. Please check the "exclusion" clause here on this section and add it to your POM xml file. [Maven Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: I checked dependency tree and found that I use com.atlassian.bamboo:atlassian-bamboo-web:jar:6.8.1 in my project and one of its dependencies is Log4J 1.2.17. Can I make exclusion for  dependent component of component that I added to my project?

Answer (score 1):

In your pom.xml file you need to locate your atlassian-bamboo-web and exclude log4j, with something similar to this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.bamboo</groupId>
    <artifactId>atlassian-bamboo-web</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then, to preserve bamboo logging, you may need to follow this migration from log4j 1.x to 2.x https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

You also need to add this dependency to override transitive dependency with lower version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-slf4j-impl` should **never** be deployed together. The former forwards Log4j API to SLF4J, the latter forwards SLF4J to Log4j API. Did you mean `log4j-1.2-api` instead?

Comment: In the question there are both log4j-slf4j-impl (added) and log4j-to-slf4j (transitive) but in different versions. In such case I would bump up log4j-to-slf4j to 2.17.1 and not add log4j-slf4j-impl implicitly